# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un registro dentro de un método de edición?

Tags: javascript, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un controlador de MVC que funciona de la siguiente manera:

```
        [HttpPost("EditRegistroIncidencias")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditRegistroIncidencias(CatRegistroIncidencias ReInci, string Obse, CatBitacoraIncidencias BitInci)
    {
        try
        {
            
            
            var RegInci = _context.CatRegistroIncidencias.Where(x => x.ReInciId == ReInci.ReInciId).First();

            if (ReInci != null)
            {

                var ListaDetalleFlujos = _context.CatDetalleFlujo.OrderBy(x => x.DetFlujoId).ToList();
                var DetalleFlujos = _context.CatDetalleFlujo.Where(x => x.DetFlujoId == RegInci.ReInciEstatusFlujo).First();
                var Flujos = _context.CatDetalleFlujo.Where(x => x.DetFlujoFlujoId == DetalleFlujos.DetFlujoFlujoId).ToList();

                var OrdenNuevo = 0;
                var NuevoIdFlujo = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < Flujos.Count; i++)
                {
                    var OrdenActual = DetalleFlujos.DetFlujoOrden;
                    if (RegInci.ReInciEstatusId != 6 || RegInci.ReInciEstatusId != 5) // Validación para que si llega un registro YA cerrado o cancelado, no permita seguir
                    {
                        if (ReInci.ReInciEstatusId == 5 || ReInci.ReInciEstatusId == 4) // Validación para cerrar registro
                        {
                            var RegistroCerrado = Flujos[i].DetFlujoId;
                            NuevoIdFlujo = RegistroCerrado;
                        }
                        else if (ReInci.ReInciEstatusId == 9 || ReInci.ReInciEstatusId == 3)
                        { // Validación para cuando el registro es regresado para revisión
                            var RegistroReiniciado = Flujos[i].DetFlujoId;
                            NuevoIdFlujo = RegistroReiniciado;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (DetalleFlujos.DetFlujoId == Flujos[i].DetFlujoId) // Validación para flujo normal
                            {
                                if (Flujos.Count != i)
                                {
                                    if (OrdenActual != Flujos.Count)
                                    {
                                        OrdenNuevo = OrdenActual + 1;
                                        var NuevoFlujo = Flujos.Where(x => x.DetFlujoOrden == OrdenNuevo).First();
                                        NuevoIdFlujo = NuevoFlujo.DetFlujoId;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }

                }

                BitInci.BitInciReInciId = ReInci.ReInciId;
                BitInci.BitInciUserId = user.UserName;
                BitInci.BitInciFecha = FechaActual;
                BitInci.BitInciObservaciones = Obse;
                BitInci.BitInciDetFlujoId = NuevoIdFlujo;

                _context.CatBitacoraIncidencias.Add(BitInci);
                _context.SaveChanges();

                RegInci.ReInciEmpId = ReInci.ReInciEmpId;
                RegInci.Fecha = ReInci.Fecha;
                RegInci.ReInciInciId = ReInci.ReInciInciId;
                RegInci.ReInciEstatusId = ReInci.ReInciEstatusId;
                RegInci.ReInciEstatusFlujo = NuevoIdFlujo;


                _context.Entry(RegInci).State = EntityState.Modified;
                
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Y cuando quiero hacer el registro de una bitácora precisamente del registro de incidencias, me marca el siguiente error: *

> The instance of Entity type cannot be tracked because another instance
> with the same key value is already being tracked

- 

Y mi función de Javascript que manda todos los datos funciona de manera correcta, es la siguiente:

```
function EditRegistroIncidencias() {
event.preventDefault();
var x = $("#EditRegistroIncidencias").valid(); // Edita el nombre
var observaciones2 = document.getElementById("ObservacionesRegistros").value;

if (x != false) {
    Swal.fire({
        title: '¿Desea Guardar los cambios?',
        text: "¡No se podrá revertir!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
        confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            var reginci = { // Edita los nombres de las variables
                ReInciId: $("#Id").val(),
                ReInciEmpId: $("#ReInciEmpIdE").val(),
                Fecha: $("#FechaE").val(),
                ReInciInciId: $("#ReInciInciIdE").val(),
                ReInciEstatusId: $("#ReInciEstatusIdE").val()
                
            }
            var observaciones = {
                Observaciones: $("#ObservacionesRegistros").val()
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/EditRegistroIncidencias", // Edita el nombre
                data: { ReInci: reginci, Obse: observaciones2 },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#btnEditRegistroIncidencias").prop("disabled", true); // Edita el nombre
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Guardando...',
                        allowEscapeKey: false,
                        allowOutsideClick: false,
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        onOpen: () => {
                            Swal.showLoading();
                        }
                    });
                },
                complete: function (data) {
                    swal({
                        type: 'success',
                        title: '¡Listo!.',
                        text: "Se ha guardado con éxito"
                    }).then((result) => {
                        location.reload();
                    });
                },

                error: function (data) {
                    alert('ERROR AL OBTENER DATOS');
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

}

He probado a la función de :

```
_context.Entry(RegInci).State = EntityState.Modified;
                
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

añadirle el Detached en lugar de Modified y no funciona.
Incluso declaré :

```
_context.Entry(RegInci).State = EntityState.Detached;
_context.Set<CatRegistroIncidencias>.Update(RegInci);
```

Y tampoco funciona. No sé si estoy haciendo algo mal o se hace de otra manera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinceramente es mucho código para analizar y sin poder probar, yo tengo la sospecha que tu problema está con el objeto RegInci, por lo que te recomiendo probar cambiar esto:

```
BitInci.BitInciReInciId = ReInci.ReInciId;
BitInci.BitInciUserId = user.UserName;
BitInci.BitInciFecha = FechaActual;
BitInci.BitInciObservaciones = Obse;
BitInci.BitInciDetFlujoId = NuevoIdFlujo;

_context.CatBitacoraIncidencias.Add(BitInci);
_context.SaveChanges();

RegInci.ReInciEmpId = ReInci.ReInciEmpId;
RegInci.Fecha = ReInci.Fecha;
RegInci.ReInciInciId = ReInci.ReInciInciId;
RegInci.ReInciEstatusId = ReInci.ReInciEstatusId;
RegInci.ReInciEstatusFlujo = NuevoIdFlujo;


_context.Entry(RegInci).State = EntityState.Modified;

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Por esto:

```
BitInci.BitInciReInciId = ReInci.ReInciId;
BitInci.BitInciUserId = user.UserName;
BitInci.BitInciFecha = FechaActual;
BitInci.BitInciObservaciones = Obse;
BitInci.BitInciDetFlujoId = NuevoIdFlujo;

_context.CatBitacoraIncidencias.Add(BitInci);

ReInci.ReInciEstatusFlujo = NuevoIdFlujo;

_context.Update(ReInci);

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Me avisas si funciona !!

Comment: Hola! Lo probé y me sigue marcando el mismo error. Ocurre precisamente en el _context.CatBitacoraIncidencias.Add(BitInci); Por lo que estuve investigando es que una conexión se queda abierta o que por estar usando el ReInciId no me permite hacer la inserción. Pero es un método que necesito registrar primero una bitácora antes de editar el registro de la incidencia

Comment: Ya logré resolver el problema. En lugar de tomar como modelo principal el Registro de Incidencias (ReInci), tomé el de bitácora de incidencias (BitInci) y pasé el campo del javascript como una propiedad de BitInci, no como la llave principal de ReInci. Y pude hacer el registro y la edición. Y justamente me sirvió con tu _context.Update(ReInci); !!! Muchas gracias!